# how to add self define tag attribution for UIView with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Assume that there is property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* tag;
```

What I wanna implement is make any subclass of UIView can set there tag, like this:

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton alloc] init...];
UILabel *lbl = [UILabel alloc]init...];
btn.tag = @"1";
lbl.tag = @"2";
```

what I try to resolve this is using category, however, it's difficult to implement setter method for instance in Category except use " Associated Objects". 
Are there any other method to implement this function?

Comment: UIKit controls already have a numeric `tag` property (and methods to find a subview by tag number, etc.). The question is why you think you need a `tag`, as there are preferable ways to handle this nowadays (e.g. subclass the superview that these are added to and have meaningfully named properties rather than cryptic `tag` values).

Comment: Yes I know, But what I need is implement by myself. It's an interview question.

Comment: I wouldn't use the name `tag` as your example in your answer. (And if they're the ones who proposed creating a string property called `tag` for UIKit controls, you just might not want to work for those guys.) But, if your question is how to extend the existing UIKit controls, without subclassing, then, yes, associated values is the way you do that.

Comment: Yes your right, you can call it as myTag. My answer is use associated object, but interviewer except another way to do it.

Comment: The other logical way would be to subclass. But, if they're precluding both subclassing (i.e. they're insisting that it must be through a category and not a subclass) and they're saying you cannot use associated values, they're really eliminating the two most logical ways to solve this. We could contort ourselves to come up with other approaches, but they all have serious code smell, IMHO.

Comment: @Rob, yes, the question really confuse me a lot. I have no idea what interviewer really want. Thank you for your help!